# Do I need to store the FB access token on the backend in my Laravel Socialite+JWT and Ionic app?

Tags: laravel, ionic2, facebook-javascript-sdk, jwt, laravel-socialite

I am slightly confused about the correct flow to Register and Login a user with cordova-plugin-facebook4 and Laravel Socialite + tymondesigns/jwt-auth. My front end is in Ionic 2 and the backend is in Laravel 5.4

**My flow:** (heavily borrowed from this [blog post](https://medium.com/@barryvdh/oauth-in-javascript-apps-with-angular-and-lumen-using-satellizer-and-laravel-socialite-bb05661c0d5c))

1. Using the cordova-plugin-facebook4 , perform a FB.login(). This returns the following json

{
    status: "connected",
    authResponse: {
        session_key: true,
        accessToken: "EAACgZAhHOaPsBAIjUUASeKSLnbEkashdkashdkhakdhakdh",
        expiresIn: 5183979,
        sig: "...",
        secret: "...",
        userID: "634565435"
    }
}

2. Post the "accessToken" to http:///auth/facebook
3. Retrieve the user profile using the Socialite "userFromToken" method.

   $profile = Socialite::driver('facebook')->userFromToken($token);
4. Check if the user exists in the DB.

IF it does create and return a new access token using JWTAuth
ELSE create a new user in the DB and return a new access token using JWTAuth

```
    $provider = "facebook"
    try{
        $profile = Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($token);
    }
    catch(Exception $exception)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'error'=>'User retrieval failed from provider'
        ],401);
    }
    //Check if the user registered earlier with this provider.
    try{
        $existingUser = User::where('provider','=',$provider)
            ->where('provider_id','=',$profile->getId())
            ->firstOrFail();
        //If user is found and no exception was raised
        if ($existingUser)
        {
            return response()->json([
                'token'=>JWTAuth::fromUser($existingUser),
                'user'=>$existingUser
            ]);
        }

    }
    catch (ModelNotFoundException $exception)
    {
        $user=new User();
            $user->email=$profile->getEmail();
            $user->name=$profile->getName();
            $user->password=$this->random_password();
            $user->provider=$provider;
            $user->provider_id=$profile->getId();
            $user->save();
        return response()->json([
            'token'=>JWTAuth::fromUser($user),
            'user'=>$user
        ]);
    }
```

**My Confusion:**

1. Are the "Login with Facebook" and "Register/Signup with Facebook" two exclusive functions? How would subsequent logins work for a mobile app after the user registers on Laravel the first time?
2. In Step 4 when I check if the user exists in the backend I'm querying the table on the "provider_id" returned by `Socialite::driver($provider)->userFromToken($token)->getId()`. I don't understand how this value is unique to a particular user.
3. In both cases for step 2 - a new JWT Auth token is created from the user and returned to the front end. I plan to save this token on the front end and use it for protected resource access. However, I'm not sure if I need to store the FB Access_Token in the DB and share it with the front end to be cached as well.

   4. How will the login process work when the app is reopened. The user should be auto logged in but would this happen via Facebook, via Laravel Social or just the locally stored JWT?

Thanks
Sam

Comment: I would recommend to store the fb id, or whatever id of any social identity, because you can remember what user is with that token, it's only an advice, but you can use the email every time to know who is.

And yes every id is unique for each user, every user has an id in fb, twitter, google, etc

In mobile you normally need the id of user to make request, i.e fb-route/uuid of the user returns maybe some information or the fb image, etc you need that id to use the fb api if the user grant permissions

You don't need to share the token, if you use JWT, just save the token of the lib

Comment: When does the access token for FB expire?
Also, is the id returned by Socialite the user id (for facebook) or an id for the provider (eg. facebook, google) or a combination of both ?

Comment: It has no expiration date, but sometimes changes to avoid hacks with that fb id, solo your identificators has to be one email, and the fb id, if the fb_id changes you can update the request if the email exists ;)